# Rails: devise_invitable, form validation errors: undefined method 'errors' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I use Devise and the `devise_invitable` gem to manage and invite users / members to my Rails app. I have some issues with form validations. I have two fields in my invitation form, one for `name` and the other for `recipient_email`. *Name is optional*. When I click submit button - either when the form is valid or not, e.g. when both fields are empty - I get the following error:

```
undefined method `errors' for false:FalseClass
```

The error point to my `invitations_controller` `create` action. This method looks like this:

```
def create

  @user = User.find_by(email: invite_params[:email])
  @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:team_id])
  already_invited = false
  # Check if the user already s invited to the team.
  @team.invitations.each do |invitation|
    if @user && invitation.recipient_email.eql?(@user.email)
      already_invited = true
    end
  end

  if already_invited
    redirect_to edit_team_path(@team), notice: "User already invited"
  else
    # The app crashes here
    super
  end
end
```

I have also customised these two `devise_invitable` methods: `after_invite_path_for` and `invite_resource(&block)`. Much based on [this tutorial.](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Invite-a-Resource-(or-User)-that-Has-Already-Signed-Up-without-Invitation) They look like this:

```
def after_invite_path_for(resource)
  team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])
  edit_team_path(team)
end

def invite_resource(&block)
  @user = User.find_by(email: invite_params[:email])
  @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:team_id])

  if @user && @user.email != current_user.email
    token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    @user.invite_existing_user!(@user, current_user, token)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    invitation = @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
    invitation.save
    @user
  else
    @user = resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter, &block)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    invitation = @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: @user.raw_invitation_token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
    invitation.save
  end
end
```

I have four relevant models, `User` (the entity that is getting invited), `Team` each user can be a `Member` (join table) of multiple `Team`. I also have a custom `Invitation` model, each `Team` can have many invitations, I use this to list invitations sent for a specific team. The invitation functionality worked before, but I had some issues when the form was invalid, for example when both fields where `empty`. To fix this I tried to enable this in `Devise.rb`:

```
config.validate_on_invite = true
```

And in my `User` model have the following:

```
devise [...], :invitable, validate_on_invite: true
```

In my user model I also have this:

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
```

And in my custom `Invitation` model I have this:

```
validates_presence_of :recipient_email
```

The issue I had before was that `invite_resource` was getting called despite invalid input, and I would create a new custom `Invitation` resource for my team.

What I want in error cases is simply:

1. Don't create or send invitation
2. Show error message

How can I get this to work when using `devise_invitable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `false` from your custom `invite_resource` implementation. The base controller calls this method and expects an ActiveRecord model instance back, then examines `errors` on that. But you're returning `false`, so it tries to execute `false.errors` - hence the problem you see when you invoke `super`.

See line 27 via:

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L25

...and the default implementation of `invite_resource` at:

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L81

...versus your complex implementation:

```
def invite_resource(&block)
  @user = User.find_by(email: invite_params[:email])
  @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:team_id])

  if @user && @user.email != current_user.email
    token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    @user.invite_existing_user!(@user, current_user, token)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    invitation = @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
    invitation.save
    @user
  else
    @user = resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter, &block)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    invitation = @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: @user.raw_invitation_token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
    invitation.save
  end
end
```

Note that the `else` case in the above evaluates to the result of `invitation.save`, which for validation errors will be `false`. You forgot the `@user` declaration as present in the above-`else` case. Just DRY up that code a bit, e.g. as follows (stylistically this might not be to everyone's taste):

```
def invite_resource(&block)
  @user = User.find_by(email: invite_params[:email])
  @team = Team.find_by(id: params[:team_id])

  invitation = if @user && @user.email != current_user.email
    token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    @user.invite_existing_user!(@user, current_user, token)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
  else
    @user = resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter, &block)
    member = @team.members.find_by(user_id: current_or_guest_user.id)
    @team.invitations.build(invitation_token: @user.raw_invitation_token, member_id: member.id, recipient_email: invite_params[:email])
  end

  invitation.save
  @user
end
```

That should at least fix your `undefined method` exception, though it leaves any validation errors on `invitation` ignored (is a `save!` in order here, with the whole thing wrapped in `User.transaction do...` to keep all those invitations atomic?).